# Is there any idiom or proverb which can be used for saying focus on the important matters?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there any idiom or proverb which can be used for saying focus on the important matters / filter out unwanted details or management by exception?

This is in regards to when you have lots of information to process, you need to know what you should pay attention to.

In software (Excel), you have the ability to define rules or apply filter, which will narrow down the results and you can focus on only what you need. One need not eye through every record one by one to identify which records meet his/her criteria.

Comment: There are several, but it's hard to tell which ones would work best. Can you give some more idea of how this should be used? What level of formality are you looking for, and who will read or hear this?

Comment: I have included some additional explanation. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It would help if you gave an example of how you want to use it. For example, are you trying to tell someone to focus on what is important or are you trying to explain what you're doing or something else?

Answer (score 3):

> *"When you focus on what is important, you work better. Even further, you achieve the goal or meet the target."*

If I take this statement as the gist of what you want to say or to address the scene, out of many, I can think of one idiom.

> *Keep your eye on the prize:* This means that you should keep your focus on achieving a positive end result.

This means, you simply filter out what is **not** important for you.